# JSON to SQL Query

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have following data:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {
    "provider_references": [{"provider_groups": [{"npi": [123456789], "tin": {"type": "ein", "value": "8987654321"}}], "provider_group_id": 0}, {"provider_groups": [{"npi": [123456789], "tin": {"type": "ein", "value": "456789123"}}], "provider_group_id": 1}]
  }
]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```

I want extract npi, provider_group_ID, ein and value. How do I write SQL query.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/F1cLTplu - `select JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0].provider_references[0].provider_groups[0].npi[0]')
  , JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0].provider_references[0].provider_groups[0].tin.type')
, JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0].provider_references[0].provider_groups[0].tin.value')`

Comment: @zedfoxus why not add an actual answer?

Comment: Will there only ever be one provider reference, one provider group, one NPI value, and one TIN value?

Comment: What are your expected results? What are your expected results if there are multiple elements in the `provider_groups` array? Multiple elements in the `npi` array?

Comment: There will be one provider reference but multiple provider groups. I have updated data sample to look like real.

Comment: @DaleK Last 5 consecutive times I typed out an answer with explanations and the question got closed. I couldn't type an answer. So, I just add give ideas in comments than writing an answer when I believe the question is likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: It's not closed. My guess is the downvotes are because you haven't done any research or tried anything.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thank you. I will keep this in mind in future.